# Logstash - ArgumentError: Setting “” hasn’t been registered

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to send a +8Go csv file to my ES server form my machine.

I use Logstash to send the file with this conf :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/karnag/Downloads/siren201703.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      #Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume (BTC),Volume (Currency),Weighted Price
      columns => ["SIREN", "NIC", "L1_NORMALISEE", "L2_NORMALISEE", "L3_NORMALISEE", "L4_NORMALISEE", "L5_NORMALISEE", "L6_NORMALISEE", "L7_NORMALISEE", "L1_DECLAREE", "L2_DECLAREE", "L3_DECLAREE", "L4_DECLAREE", "L5_DECLAREE", "L6_DECLAREE", "L7_DECLAREE", "NUMVOIE", "INDREP", "TYPVOIE", "LIBVOIE", "CODPOS", "CEDEX", "RPET", "LIBREG", "DEPET", "ARRONET", "CTONET", "COMET", "LIBCOM", "DU", "TU", "UU", "EPCI", "TCD", "ZEMET", "SIEGE", "ENSEIGNE", "IND_PUBLIPO", "DIFFCOM", "AMINTRET", "NATETAB", "LIBNATETAB", "APET700", "LIBAPET", "DAPET", "TEFET", "LIBTEFET", "EFETCENT", "DEFET", "ORIGINE", "DCRET", "DDEBACT", "ACTIVNAT", "LIEUACT", "ACTISURF", "SAISONAT", "MODET", "PRODET", "PRODPART", "AUXILT", "NOMEN_LONG", "SIGLE", "NOM", "PRENOM", "CIVILITE", "RNA", "NICSIEGE", "RPEN", "DEPCOMEN", "ADR_MAIL", "NJ", "LIBNJ", "APEN700", "LIBAPEN", "DAPEN", "APRM", "ESS", "DATEESS", "TEFEN", "LIBTEFEN", "EFENCENT", "DEFEN", "CATEGORIE", "DCREN", "AMINTREN", "MONOACT", "MODEN", "PRODEN", "ESAANN", "TCA", "ESAAPEN", "ESASEC1N", "ESASEC2N", "ESASEC3N", "ESASEC4N", "VMAJ", "VMAJ1", "VMAJ2", "VMAJ3", "DATEMAJ"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://192.168.10.19:8080/"
     index => "siren"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

And I got this error:

```
[2017-03-15T10:23:04,628][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<ArgumentError: Setting "" hasn't been registered>, :backtrace=>["/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:29:in `get_setting'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:61:in `set_value'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:80:in `merge'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:80:in `merge'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:115:in `validate_all'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:210:in `execute'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:183:in `run'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "/Users/karnag/Documents/Epitech/ElasticStack/Logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:71:in `(root)'"]}
```

I can't find where is the typo in my conf file (clearly there is something wrong here).

Thanks.